# Can you edit a scheduled release deployment in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I need to edit the schedule of a single release in my ADO pipeline. For now, I've canceled the deployment and now have to manually deploy at the time requested. I find this extremely inconvenient. I don't see how pre-deployment conditions can be edited:[image]

Comment: I don't think you have enough rights on the release pipeline as it should show `Schedule` in `Pre-deployment conditions`, also make sure you are looking in the right stage.

Comment: @Sibtain I am a project admin, when I go to edit release I can see the schedule. I might have not clarified my situation. I'm trying to edit the scheduled deployment on a stage in a release that's waiting to be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a scheduled task in task scheduler to invoke the REST API call:

1. Cancel the scheduled deployment of the stage you intend to re-schedule, I discovered that you cannot override a schedule in Azure DevOps if one is set:

   [image]
2. Invoke a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#environmentstatus) call using something like powershell. Remember that you have to have the ability to authenticate to Azure DevOps with something like a PAT or [azure AD token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops).
3. If you have a Windows server for example, use task scheduler to create a task to run the api call (you could even add a parameter for a user to input the release number in the task) and then set your schedule.

*Note: The account running the task has to have Log on as a batch job rights and is able to authenticate to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add pre-deployment approval:

[image]

Then deploy your release again. Then you may plan your deployment on the Approval page:

[image]